# DNN Persona bar, error 500 on API/personaBar/localization/gettable?culture=en-US

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

After logging in DNN (v. 09.01.01 (129)) thru the /login interface,

The site makes space for the DNN bar, but the DNN bar does not actually appear.

After which in console we see this particular error

`/API/personaBar/localization/gettable?culture=en-US:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

We have tried all the suggestions in DNN's forums [here](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/persona-bar-not-displaying-1), 
But none seem to work (deleting the LocalResources.en-US file, checking Permissions..)

How ca nwe diagnose the actual issue, and how do we restore the persona Bar?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say, but here's some options :

- If you do a custom module, make sure it not overwrite Newtonsoft.json.dll and System.web.http.dll, try overwrite the library with your backup.
- Make sure there's no virtual directory under your website.
- Try upgrade it to latest DNN.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to try to get additional details about the error. First try recreating it then connect to your SQL server to run a query or two.

You can try to query the EventLog table to try to find the specific error. From that table row, you'll need to grab the ExceptionHash value and then query the Exceptions table to try to get details.

```
select top 5 * from eventlog 
where exceptionhash is not null
order by logcreatedate desc 

select * from exceptions where exceptionhash = '###'
```

(replace ### with the hash found in the first results)

From the exceptions table you'll want to look at the Message and StackTrace columns for any details that might point you in the direction of what the actual issue is.

You'll also likely find that upgrading to the most recent release may fix your problems.